# Get Channel Subscriptions with TWITCH API

Tags: twitch, twitch-api

Iam trying to get the Channel Subs of a Channel with the following call:

```
https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/<CHANNELID>/subscriptions?client_id=XXX&oauth_token=XXX
```

But i get always this response:

```
{
  "error": "Forbidden",
  "status": 403,
  "message": "Unable to access channel subscribers of <CHANNEL>"
}
```

Can you please tell me, what I need to pass, that i get the permissions?

Thanks, Greetings

Answer (score 0):

If you are using new Twitch API you should send token in your authorization header starting with Bearer keyword. If you are using API v5 then you should add Oauth keyword. In your example you are trying to send it in query parameters.

Select the one which is correct for you.

In the new Twitch API:

```
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer <access token>" https://api.twitch.tv/helix/
```

In Twitch API v5:

```
curl -H "Authorization: OAuth <access token>" https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/
```

You can also find more information in the official documentation: https://dev.twitch.tv/docs/authentication/